# Random Array - Processing / Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am developing an array with images, as one can see below:

```
int maxImages = 4; // Total # of images
int imageIndex = 0; // Initial image to be displayed is the first

// Declaring an array of images.
PImage[] images = new PImage[maxImages]; 

void setup() {

 for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i ++ ) {
    images[i] = loadImage( "shape" + i + ".jpg" ); 
  }

}
```

I am trying to implement a logic that if this particular variable equal to 1 than it does a randomisation and selects one image from the above array. Below is the code I am implementing:

```
void draw() {

image(images[imageIndex],0,0);
if(id == 1){   
imageIndex = int(random(images.length));
}

}
```

With the above implementation, when id is equal to 1 the randomisation process is randomising all the images in the array. I want the random to work only only once and selects only 1 image from the array.

What can I do to implement the above ?

Comment: Have you tried opening the javadoc, and looking for "Random"?

Comment: But id is equal to 1 many times. You need to have a way to find out if the choice has been already made. Create a `bool` to hold the state

Comment: @JBNizet I did cause if i didn't I would have managed to compile the above. I am just seeking some help in how to stop the images being random constantly for the array length

Comment: The code above does not compile, so...

Comment: @JBNizet the above are snippets from my total code, I didn't paste the whole code. I only shown the relevant parts to where I got stuck

Comment: Your description of what is happening is not making much sense.  What does your method "random()" do?

Comment: And these, insufficient relevant parts do not compile. `int(random(images.length))` is not valid Java code. There's no way a method is called `int`.

Comment: @BigBadaboom it randomising the array length to assign a number to the variable imageIndex. ImageIndex is then used in the above method image() where it is replacing the images

Comment: @JBNizet I have used this source to compile that : http://www.learningprocessing.com/examples/chapter-15/example-15-3-swapping-images/

Comment: @Munnnnn Your probgram will not compile at first place. Because you have syntax error.

Comment: I have no idea what this code is, but it's not Java. If it is, it's invalid Java.

Comment: Can I speak to someone privately and then update the question accordingly so I can explain myself better with regards to my issue

Comment: You should rather write your own code, make it compile, and then ask a question, containing all the relevant, compiling code.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to execute a random on my array and get only one randomisation then the whole array length ?

Comment: Have you tried opening the javadoc, and looking for "Random"?

Comment: @JBNizet the problem isnt on the random as that works perfectly fine. My issue is that when id is equal to 1 it randoms the images 4 times since I am randomising the array length. I need to figure out a way that I only random one number from the aray

Comment: You're asking how to fix code that doesn't work. It's unclear what doesn't work, the posted code is not sufficient to identify the problem, and it's not even valid, compiling Java code. So, do YOUR part of the job, by writing valid Java code, explaining clearly what the problem is, and posting all the relevant, valid, compiling Java code.

Comment: @JBNizet I didn't all code since I am using reactivision integrated with processing, so you need to have fiducials printed and several libraries installed to compile the whole code. It is not fair to post all the chunks of code here

Comment: Then write a minimal, but complete Java code example that reproduces the problem. I don't have any idea what reactivision and processing are, but if the posted code is in a language other than Java, then tag your question with this language, not with Java.

Comment: @JBNizet you should research like u stated I should do before answering any questions! and yes the above code is Java.

Comment: No, it's not. `int` is the primitive type. It can not be used as a method as it is in the code you posted. And I'm not answering the question. I'm commenting on your bad, unclear question, to tell you how it should be improved in order for YOU to get an answer to YOUR problem, for free, from us. Also, I don't see how I could have researched about processing and reactivision, given that you omitted to say anything about it in your question.

Comment: @JBNizet I did have them as tags in my question but for some reason someone edited my question and removed them. The int() is a function used to convert a floating point random number to an integer. The scope of this community is as you stated to help each other if I post good questions and code, however if one doesn't do that you have to help and assist rather than finding each and every single item which is wrong and blaming the person asking the question. I am a beginner to here, I don;t think you started as PRO neither !!

Comment: I already told you several things to do. 1. stop pretending it's Java code, since it's not. 2. post valid, complete Java code. 3. Explain what the problem is with the code. We should be able to reproduce it, or at least have all the information in the code to disgnose the problem. There is no such thing as an `int()` function in Java. Java doesn't even have functions. You have not made any change to your question despite the 3 downvotes you got, and the many comments you had telling you that your question is not clear. Remember: you are the one needing help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the class `java.util.Random`.  It has a `nextInt(int n)` method that returns a number between 0 and n-1 (inclusive).

Comment: The random is working in my above code, my problem is imageIndex is being executed 4 times as per the array length. I only want it to execute a random image from the array once

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to pick an element from an array.

```
Random generator = new Random();
PImage image = images[generator.nextInt(images.length)];
```

We cannot help you until you improve your question.